# Simulate typing into chromium omnibox in desktop for Perf testing

Tags: performance-testing, chromium, address-bar, omnibox

I am trying to see if there is anyway I can programmatically typing into chromium's omnibox via script/automation/etc for Perf testing.

I want to test the following:
1. Client side: for each keystroke in Omnibox, I want to measure the rendering speed of the Omnibox when there are suggestions coming from server side. This is logged in the histogram right now.
2. Server side: for each keystroke in Omnibox, I want to measure the response time. This is also logged in histogram right now. 
And we want to run across many keystrokes, with different queries to cover above 2 areas automatically.

I know chromium's test framework Catapult has benchmarks measure the Perf/system health, however the current tests are only for Chrome Android mobile apps. Not for chromium desktop app.

And I don't see any existing tests in Catapult that can control the chromium desktop app's omnibox and simulating typing into the omnibox.

Is there any way I can do this, it does not need to be Catapult framework.

Comment: Help us to understand your goals better?  Are you performance testing Chromium as a client?  Are you performance testing the autosuggestions which come back as part of your work for Google?   Your end goal on client performance vs server performance is unclear from your post

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. Let me update the asks.

Answer (score 0):

If you find an issue in "rendering" (Which you have not defined as common or technical), who do you expect to report this to for a defect report and a fix on your timeline?